# Email Alert for Inserting/updating/removing files inside folder in windows7

Tags: windows, directory, alert, shared-directory

i have above mentioned case happen at our company, they need to know under certain folder whether its shared or not if any files inserted or removed or update to send alert by email periodically for that action, any thought an ideas please

Answer (score 0):

You can fairly easily create an application in C# that monitors a folder using the FileSystemMonitor class:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

With that you can then have it perform whatever actions you want.